# Trying to get my show-method to work (Non static method cannot be referenced from static context)

Tags: java

Sorry, I am very new to programming for university. This is a practise question for our test and is set up on code runner. The entire main method and all the classes, methods, constructors and variables were already give to me and I have to make the shown class to print out what I have written. But `Bride.getAge()` and `Location.getSuburb()` in the `println` will not work. Do I need to add something else in?

```
public class Location {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bride person = new Bride("Amy Cronos", 29);
        Location place = new Location("Tonsley", "South Rd");
        Wedding wed = new Wedding(person,place);

        show(wed);
    }

    public static void show(Wedding wed){  
        System.out.println("Wedding data:" );
        System.out.println("Bride: " + wed.getBride() + ", age: " + Bride.getAge);
        System.out.println("Location: " + wed.getPlace() + ", suburb: " + Location.getSuburb());
    }

    private String suburb;
    private String street;

    Location(String suburb, String street){
        this.suburb = suburb;
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getSuburb(){
          return suburb;
    }

    public String getStreet(){
          return street;
    }

    public class Bride {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        Bride(String name, int age){
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge(){
            return age;
        }
    }

    public class Wedding {
        private Bride person;
        private Location place;

        Wedding(Bride person, Location place){
            this.person = person;
            this.place = place;
        }

        public Bride getPerson(){
            return person;
        }

        public Location getPlace(){
            return place;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More precisely​, `wed.getPlace().getSuburb()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: In the future, please cut down your source code to the minimum that exhibits the behaviour you are curious about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the below lines in `show` method

```
System.out.println("Bride: " + wed.getBride() + ", age: " + wed.getPerson().getAge());

System.out.println("Location: " + wed.getPlace() + ", suburb: " + wed.getPlace().getSuburb());
```

Since you are using Class names with methods, `Bride.getAge()` and `Location.getSuburb()`, these methods are considered static. Hence the error. Since these are not static methods, you need to use the objects of the class to access them rather than Class names.

Answer (score 0):

you have passed object of class Bride and Location so you need to get value like below code : Try with below code and try to understands object in java , static is different thing .

```
public static void show(Wedding wed){

System.out.println("Wedding data:" );
System.out.println("Bride: " + wed.getPerson() + ", age: " + wed.getPerson().getAge());
System.out.println("Location: " + wed.getPlace() + ", suburb: " + wed.getPlace().getSuburb());

}
```

Comment: `wed.getPerson().getAge` is incomplete, you forgot (like OP) to add the `()`

Comment: I'm not sure that this will print _exactly_ as OP requires.  I think there'll need to be a `toString` method in `Bride` and `Location`.

Comment: `wed.getBride()` 

 `wed.getBride().getAge());`

`wed.getPlace()`

 `wed.getPlace().getSuburb());` 

when using these methods it prints out like this on code runner: 

`Wedding data:

Bride: Bride@1af1bd6, age: 29

Location: Location@f4c7f77, suburb: Tonsley`

 maybe the code runner has a bug.

Comment: that's  right values you have passes while making objet. are print .

Comment: @B.Fall You can either write `toString` methods in `Location` and `Bride`, as I said earlier; or you can change your code to print `wed.getBride().getName()` and `wed.getPlace().getStreet()` instead of `wed.getBride()` and `wed.getPlace()`.

Comment: @Danwood Ibn Kareem Thank you I just saw your comment, all fixed I was just reading the code wrong as I didn't write it all myself it was given to me. Thank you a lot!